# A Java program interfacing with Gnuplot for generating triangle wave plots

Tags: java, mathematics, exercise

**Intro**

I have [this repository](https://github.com/coderodde/TriangleWavePlotter.java/).

Given this command

```
java -jar TriangleWavePlotter-1.6.jar --amplitude=2 --period=4 --shift=-1 --xRangeStart=-12 --xRangeEnd=12 --yRangeStart=-3 --yRangeEnd=3 %USERPROFILE%/OneDrive/Desktop/TriangleWave.png
```

the program will produce

[image: Triangle wave]

**Code**

**`com.github.coderodde.gnuplot.trianglewave.TriangleWavePlotter.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.gnuplot.trianglewave;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * This class implements a triangle wave plotter.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 17, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 17, 2023)
 */
public final class TriangleWavePlotter {
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
            Logger.getLogger(TriangleWavePlotter.class.getSimpleName());
    
    private static final String TRIANGULAR_WAVE_GNUPLOT_FILE_NAME = 
            "triangle-wave.plt";
    
    private static final String TEMPORARY_PLOT_SCRIPT_PREFIX = "triangle-wave-";
    private static final String TEMPORARY_PLOT_SCRIPT_SUFFIX = ".plt";
    private static final String WINDOWS_USERPROFILE = "%USERPROFILE%";
    private static final String LINUX_USERPROFILE = "~";
    
    private static final class Anchors {
        static final String PERIOD           = "{PERIOD}"          ;
        static final String AMPLITUDE        = "{AMPLITUDE}"       ;
        static final String SHIFT            = "{SHIFT}"           ;
        static final String COLOR            = "{COLOR}"           ;
        static final String LINE_WIDTH       = "{LINE_WIDTH}"      ;
        static final String X_RANGE_START    = "{X_RANGE_START}"   ;
        static final String X_RANGE_END      = "{X_RANGE_END}"     ;
        static final String Y_RANGE_START    = "{Y_RANGE_START}"   ;
        static final String Y_RANGE_END      = "{Y_RANGE_END}"     ;
        static final String PLOT_WIDTH       = "{PLOT_WIDTH}"      ;
        static final String PLOT_HEIGHT      = "{PLOT_HEIGHT}"     ;  
        static final String OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "{OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}";
    }
    
    private static final class CommandLineArguments {
        static final String PERIOD        = "--period"     ;
        static final String AMPLITUDE     = "--amplitude"  ;
        static final String SHIFT         = "--shift"      ;
        static final String COLOR         = "--color"      ;
        static final String LINE_WIDTH    = "--lineWidth"  ;
        static final String X_RANGE_START = "--xRangeStart";
        static final String X_RANGE_END   = "--xRangeEnd"  ;
        static final String Y_RANGE_START = "--yRangeStart";
        static final String Y_RANGE_END   = "--yRangeEnd"  ;
        static final String PLOT_WIDTH    = "--plotWidth"  ;
        static final String PLOT_HEIGHT   = "--plotHeight" ;   
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TriangleWavePlotter().run(args);
    }
    
    private TriangleWavePlotter() {}
    
    void run(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("No output PNG file name provided.");
            return;
        }
        
        if (args[0].equals("--help")) {
            printHelp();
            return;
        }
        
        String outputFileName = args[args.length - 1];
        String homeDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home");
        
        if (outputFileName.startsWith(WINDOWS_USERPROFILE)) {
            outputFileName = 
                    homeDirectory
                    + File.separator
                    + outputFileName.substring(WINDOWS_USERPROFILE.length());
        } else if (outputFileName.startsWith(LINUX_USERPROFILE)) {
            outputFileName = 
                    homeDirectory
                    + File.separator
                    + outputFileName.substring(LINUX_USERPROFILE.length());
        }
        
        String plotTemplate;
        
        try {
            plotTemplate = readTriangularWaveGnuplotFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE,
                    "Could not read the Gnuplot template file.", 
                    ex);
            
            System.exit(1);
            return;
        }
        
        TriangleWavePlotterConfiguration triangleWavePlotterConfiguration = 
                buildTriangleWavePlotterConfiguration(args);
        
        String gnuplotScript = 
                computeGnuplotScript(
                        plotTemplate,
                        outputFileName,
                        triangleWavePlotterConfiguration);
        
        try {
            generatePNGFile(outputFileName, gnuplotScript);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE,
                    "I/O exception while generating the plot PNG.", 
                    ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE,
                    "Interrupted while generating the plot PNG.",
                    ex);
        }
    }
    
    private static File getTemporaryGnuplotFile() throws IOException {
        return File.createTempFile(TEMPORARY_PLOT_SCRIPT_PREFIX,
                                   TEMPORARY_PLOT_SCRIPT_SUFFIX);
    }
    
    private static void generatePNGFile(String plotPNGFileName,
                                        String gnuplotScript) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File temporaryScriptFile = getTemporaryGnuplotFile();
        Files.write(temporaryScriptFile.toPath(), gnuplotScript.getBytes());
        
        String[] commands = { 
            "gnuplot.exe",
            temporaryScriptFile.getAbsolutePath() 
        };
        
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
        int returnStatus = process.waitFor();
        
        if (returnStatus != 0) {
            System.err.println(
                    "Gnuplot seems to fail, return status: " + returnStatus);
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                    "Generated the plot in " + plotPNGFileName);
        }
        
        if (!temporaryScriptFile.delete()) {
            System.gc();
            temporaryScriptFile.deleteOnExit();
        }
    }
    
    private String readTriangularWaveGnuplotFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = 
                getClass()
               .getClassLoader()
               .getResourceAsStream(TRIANGULAR_WAVE_GNUPLOT_FILE_NAME);
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");
        }
        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    
    private TriangleWavePlotterConfiguration 
        buildTriangleWavePlotterConfiguration(String[] args) {
        
        TriangleWavePlotterConfiguration triangleWavePlotterConfiguration = 
                new TriangleWavePlotterConfiguration();
        
        int index = 0;
        
        for (String argument : args) {
            if (index < args.length - 1) {
                processArgument(triangleWavePlotterConfiguration, argument);
            }
                
            index++;
        }
        
        return triangleWavePlotterConfiguration;
    }
        
    private void processArgument(
            TriangleWavePlotterConfiguration triangleWavePlotterConfiguration,
            String argument) {
    
        String command = argument.split("=")[0];
        String param   = argument.split("=")[1];
            
        if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.PERIOD)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                    .setPeriod(Double.parseDouble(param));
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.AMPLITUDE)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                    .setAmplitude(Double.parseDouble(param));
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.SHIFT)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration.setShift(
                    Double.parseDouble(param));
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.COLOR)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration.setColor(param);
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.LINE_WIDTH)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                    .setLineWidth(Integer.parseInt(param));
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.X_RANGE_START)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                    .setXRangeStart(Double.parseDouble(param));
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.X_RANGE_END)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                    .setXRangeEnd(Double.parseDouble(param));
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.Y_RANGE_START)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                    .setYRangeStart(Double.parseDouble(param));
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.Y_RANGE_END)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                    .setYRangeEnd(Double.parseDouble(param));
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.PLOT_WIDTH)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration.setPlotWidth(param);
        } else if (command.startsWith(CommandLineArguments.PLOT_HEIGHT)) {
            triangleWavePlotterConfiguration.setPlotHeight(param);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Unknown command = '" + command + "'");
        }
    }
        
    private String computeGnuplotScript(
            String plotTemplate,
            String outputFileName,
            TriangleWavePlotterConfiguration triangleWavePlotterConfiguration) {
        
        return plotTemplate
                .replace(
                        Anchors.PERIOD, 
                        Double.toString(
                                triangleWavePlotterConfiguration.getPeriod()))
                .replace(
                        Anchors.AMPLITUDE,
                        Double.toString(
                                triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                                        .getAmplitude()))
                .replace(
                        Anchors.SHIFT,
                        Double.toString(
                                triangleWavePlotterConfiguration.getShift()))
                .replace(
                        Anchors.COLOR, 
                        triangleWavePlotterConfiguration.getColor())
                .replace(
                        Anchors.LINE_WIDTH, 
                        Integer.toString(
                                triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                                        .getLineWidth())) 
                .replace(
                        Anchors.X_RANGE_START, 
                        Double.toString(
                                triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                                        .getXRangeStart()))
                .replace(
                        Anchors.X_RANGE_END, 
                        Double.toString(
                                triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                                        .getXRangeEnd()))
                .replace(
                        Anchors.Y_RANGE_START,
                        Double.toString(
                                triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                                        .getYRangeStart()))
                .replace(
                        Anchors.Y_RANGE_END, 
                        Double.toString(
                                triangleWavePlotterConfiguration
                                        .getYRangeEnd()))
                .replace(
                        Anchors.PLOT_WIDTH, 
                        triangleWavePlotterConfiguration.getPlotWidth())
                .replace(
                        Anchors.PLOT_HEIGHT, 
                        triangleWavePlotterConfiguration.getPlotHeight())
                .replace(Anchors.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outputFileName);
    }
    
    private void printHelp() {
        String jarFileName;
        
        try {
            jarFileName = getJarFileName();
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not get the JAR file name.", ex);
            System.exit(1);
            return;
        }
        
        System.out.println(
        """
        java -jar %s [OPTIONS] OUTPUT_FILE_NAME
        Where OPTIONS can have:
            --period=PERIOD       sets the period, positive floating-point-value
            --amplitude=AMPLITUDE sets the amplitude, positive floating-point value
            --shift               sets the shift, floating-point value
            --color               sets the line color, long or short RGB value, or predefined color name
            --lineWidth           sets the line width, positive integer
            --xRangeStart         sets the X-range start, floating-point value
            --xRangeEnd           sets the X-range end, floating-point value
            --yRangeStart         sets the Y-range start, floating-point value
            --yRangeEnd           sets the Y-range end, floating-point value
            --plotWidth           sets the plot width, string
            --plotHeight          sets the plot height, string
        """.formatted(jarFileName));
    }
    
    private String getJarFileName() throws URISyntaxException {
        String absolutePath = getClass()
          .getProtectionDomain()
          .getCodeSource()
          .getLocation()
          .toURI()
          .getPath();
        
        String[] pathComponents = absolutePath.split("/");
        return pathComponents[pathComponents.length - 1];
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.gnuplot.trianglewave.TriangleWavePlotterConfiguration.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.gnuplot.trianglewave;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * This class holds all the configuration parameters for plotting a 
 * triangle wave.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 17, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 17, 2023)
 */
public final class TriangleWavePlotterConfiguration {
    
    private static final Pattern SHORT_COLOR_RGB_HEX = 
            Pattern.compile("#[0-9A-F]{3}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    
    private static final class Defaults {
        static final double PERIOD        = 2.0 * Math.PI ;
        static final double AMPLITUDE     = 1.0           ;
        static final double SHIFT         = 0.0           ;
        static final String COLOR         = "#ffd500"     ;
        static final int LINE_WIDTH       = 8             ;
        static final double X_RANGE_START = -4.0 * Math.PI;
        static final double X_RANGE_END   =  4.0 * Math.PI;
        static final double Y_RANGE_START = -1.5          ;
        static final double Y_RANGE_END   = 1.5           ;
        static final String PLOT_WIDTH    = "960"         ;
        static final String PLOT_HEIGHT   = "600"         ;
    }
    
    private double period      = Defaults.PERIOD       ;      
    private double amplitude   = Defaults.AMPLITUDE    ;
    private double shift       = Defaults.SHIFT        ;
    private String color       = Defaults.COLOR        ;
    private int lineWidth      = Defaults.LINE_WIDTH   ;
    private double xRangeStart = Defaults.X_RANGE_START;
    private double xRangeEnd   = Defaults.X_RANGE_END  ;
    private double yRangeStart = Defaults.Y_RANGE_START;
    private double yRangeEnd   = Defaults.Y_RANGE_END  ;
    private String plotWidth   = Defaults.PLOT_WIDTH   ;
    private String plotHeight  = Defaults.PLOT_HEIGHT  ; 

    public double getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }
    
    public void setPeriod(double period) {
        this.period = requireDoubleIsPositive(period);
    }
    
    public double getAmplitude() {
        return amplitude;
    }
    
    public void setAmplitude(double amplitude) {
        this.amplitude = requireDoubleIsPositive(amplitude);
    }
    
    public double getShift() {
        return shift;
    }
    
    public void setShift(double shift) {
        double actualShift = shift % (2.0 * Math.PI);
        
        if (actualShift < 0.0) {
            actualShift += 2.0 * Math.PI;
        }
        
        this.shift = actualShift;
    }
    
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = validateHexColor(color);
    }

    public int getLineWidth() {
        return lineWidth;
    }

    public void setLineWidth(int lineWidth) {
        if (lineWidth < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Line width is too small: " 
                            + lineWidth 
                            + ". Must be at least 1.");
        }
        
        this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    }

    public double getXRangeStart() {
        return xRangeStart;
    }

    public void setXRangeStart(double xRangeStart) {
        this.xRangeStart = requireFiniteDouble(xRangeStart);
    }

    public double getXRangeEnd() {
        return xRangeEnd;
    }

    public void setXRangeEnd(double xRangeEnd) {
        this.xRangeEnd = requireFiniteDouble(xRangeEnd);
    }

    public double getYRangeStart() {
        return yRangeStart;
    }

    public void setYRangeStart(double yRangeStart) {
        this.yRangeStart = requireFiniteDouble(yRangeStart);
    }

    public double getYRangeEnd() {
        return yRangeEnd;
    }

    public void setYRangeEnd(double yRangeEnd) {
        this.yRangeEnd = requireFiniteDouble(yRangeEnd);
    }

    public String getPlotWidth() {
        return plotWidth;
    }

    public void setPlotWidth(String plotWidth) {
        this.plotWidth = plotWidth;
    }

    public String getPlotHeight() {
        return plotHeight;
    }

    public void setPlotHeight(String plotHeight) {
        this.plotHeight = plotHeight;
    }
    
    private static double requireFiniteDouble(double d) {
        if (Double.isNaN(d)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input double is NaN.");
        }
        
        if (Double.isInfinite(d)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input double is inifinite in absolute value.");
        }
        
        return d;
    }
    
    private static double requireDoubleIsPositive(double d) {
        if (Double.isNaN(d)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input double is NaN.");
        }
        
        if (d <= 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input double is not positive.");
        }
        
        if (Double.isInfinite(d)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input double is infinite.");
        }
        
        return d;
    }
    
    static String validateHexColor(String hexColorCandidate) {
        Matcher matcherShoftRGBHex = 
                SHORT_COLOR_RGB_HEX.matcher(hexColorCandidate);
        
        if (matcherShoftRGBHex.matches()) {
            return convertShortRGBToLong(hexColorCandidate);
        }
        
        // Perhaps, it's a color name. Just return and wish for the good.
        return hexColorCandidate;
    }
    
    private static String convertShortRGBToLong(String hexColor) {
        char r = hexColor.charAt(1);
        char g = hexColor.charAt(2);
        char b = hexColor.charAt(3);
        
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("#")
                .append(r)
                .append(r)
                .append(g)
                .append(g)
                .append(b)
                .append(b)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

**`triangle-wave.plt:`**

```
p = {PERIOD}
a = {AMPLITUDE}
s = {SHIFT}

set key noautotitle
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '{COLOR}' linewidth {LINE_WIDTH}

set xrange [{X_RANGE_START}:{X_RANGE_END}]
set yrange [{Y_RANGE_START}:{Y_RANGE_END}]

# set xtics 0, 1 format "%d"

set terminal pngcairo enhanced size {PLOT_WIDTH},{PLOT_HEIGHT}
set output '{OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}'

f(x) = (4 * a / p) * (x - s - (p / 2) * floor(2 * (x - s) / p + 0.5)) * (-1) ** floor(2 * (x - s) / p + 0.5)
plot f(x) with lines ls 1

replot
exit
```

**Critique request**

As always, please tell me whatever comes to mind.